# Ordering results in SQL select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Suppose I have a table called `Events` with data similar to the following:

```
  ID |      Name      |    ParentEvent
 ----+----------------+-----------------
   0 |   Happy Event  |       NULL
   1 |    Sad Event   |       NULL
   2 |Very Happy Event|        0
   3 | Very Sad Event |        1
   4 | Happiest Event |        2
   5 |Unpleasant Event|        1
```

How can I query this table to get results returned in a way such that

- Events with that have a non-null `ParentEvent` appear directly after the event with the `ID` mathching the `ParentEvent`
- Events with a null `ParentEvent` have a depth of 0. If an event has a depth of *n*, any event that it is a parent to has a depth of *n + 1*.
- As long as the results satisfy the previous two conditions, the order the results appear in does not matter.

For the table given above, I would like to get a result set that looks like

```
  ID |      Name      |  ParentEvent |  Depth |
 ----+----------------+--------------+--------+
   0 |   Happy Event  |      NULL    |    0   |  
   2 |Very Happy Event|       0      |    1   |
   4 | Happiest Event |       2      |    2   |
   1 |    Sad Event   |      NULL    |    0   |
   3 | Very Sad Event |       1      |    1   |
   5 |Unpleasant Event|       1      |    1   |
```

How can I construct an SQL query to get this result set? I am using T-SQL, but if you can do this in any flavor of SQL please go ahead and answer.

Comment: Oracle uses a CONNECT BY clause

Comment: Which SQL Server / ASE version ?

Comment: yes - but OP asked for any solution also..  maybe will help in the investigation

Comment: i did not search but you may for example find some article or reference to CONNECT BY solutions in T SQL

Comment: For SQL2008+ you could try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/20176962/924077

Comment: is it only for 2 levels?

Comment: @M.Ali: You seem to have misunderstood the question - you need to read the conditions stated in the question to understand why the results are ordered the way they originally were. In any case, please don't edit code and output in other people's questions as doing so can change the meaning of the questions entirely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following queries all return the exact result set you asked for. All of these work by calculating the full path to the root nodes, and using some technique for making that path able to be ordered by.

SQL Server 2008 and up. Here, by converting to the `hierarchyid` data type, SQL Server handles the ordering properly.

```
WITH Data AS (
   SELECT
      ID,
      Name,
      ParentID,
      Depth = 0,
      Ancestry = '/' + Convert(varchar(max), ID) + '/'
   FROM
      hierarchy
   WHERE
      ParentID IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      H.ID,
      H.Name,
      H.ParentID,
      D.Depth + 1,
      Ancestry = D.Ancestry + Convert(varchar(max), H.ID) + '/'
   FROM
      Data D
      INNER JOIN hierarchy H
         ON H.ParentID = D.ID
)
SELECT
   ID,
   Name,
   ParentID,
   Depth
FROM Data
ORDER BY Convert(hierarchyid, Ancestry);
```

SQL Server 2005 and up. We can convert the ID values to string and pad them out so they sort.

```
WITH Data AS (
   SELECT
      ID,
      Name,
      ParentID,
      Depth = 0,
      Ancestry = Right('0000000000' + Convert(varchar(max), ID), 10)
   FROM
      hierarchy
   WHERE
      ParentID IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      H.ID,
      H.Name,
      H.ParentID,
      Depth + 1,
      Ancestry = D.Ancestry + Right('0000000000' + Convert(varchar(max), H.ID), 10)
   FROM
      Data D
      INNER JOIN hierarchy H
         ON H.ParentID = D.ID
)
SELECT
   ID,
   Name,
   ParentID,
   Depth
FROM Data
ORDER BY Ancestry;
```

Also we can use `varbinary` (otherwise, this is the same as the prior query):

```
WITH Data AS (
   SELECT
      ID,
      Name,
      ParentID,
      Depth = 0,
      Ancestry = Convert(varbinary(max), Convert(varbinary(4), ID))
   FROM
      hierarchy
   WHERE
      ParentID IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      H.ID,
      H.Name,
      H.ParentID,
      Depth + 1,
      Ancestry = D.Ancestry + Convert(varbinary(4), H.ID)
   FROM
      Data D
      INNER JOIN hierarchy H
         ON H.ParentID = D.ID
)
SELECT
   ID,
   Name,
   ParentID,
   Depth
FROM Data
ORDER BY Ancestry;
```

SQL Server 2000 and up, allowing a tree a maximum of 800 levels deep:

```
SELECT
   *,
   Ancestry = CASE WHEN ParentID IS NULL THEN Convert(varchar(8000), Right('0000000000' + Convert(varchar(10), ID), 10)) ELSE '' END,
   Depth = 0
INTO #hierarchy
FROM hierarchy;

WHILE @@RowCount > 0 BEGIN
   UPDATE H
   SET
      H.Ancestry = P.Ancestry + Right('0000000000' + Convert(varchar(8000), H.ID), 10),
      H.Depth = P.Depth + 1
   FROM
      #hierarchy H
      INNER JOIN #hierarchy P
         ON H.ParentID = P.ID
   WHERE
      H.Ancestry = ''
      AND P.Ancestry <> '';
END;

SELECT
   ID,
   Name,
   ParentID,
   Depth
FROM #hierarchy
ORDER BY Ancestry;

DROP TABLE #hierarchy;
```

The same `varbinary` conversion can be done, allowing up to 2000 levels deep.

Comment: Text from question : `As long as the results satisfy the previous two conditions, the order the results appear in does not matter`

Comment: @ErikE I did not see your answer until after I posted mine. You had the same idea, but posted before I did.

Comment: "The same varbinary conversion can be done, allowing up to ***2000*** levels deep"? (8000 / SizeOf(int), but perhaps I got it wrong)

Comment: Correct, @Andriy, and not for the first time, Thanks for keeping me in my toes!

Answer (score 1):

This is just add to M.Ali's answer. I realize the OP said, "As long as the results satisfy the previous two conditions, the order the results appear in does not matter". However, by adding a column to the query that keeps track of the hierarchy path, it is possible to display the results the same as in the question.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID, 
    NAME,
    ParentID,
    0 as Depth,
    convert(varbinary(max), convert(varbinary(2), ID)) as ThePath
  FROM   hierarchy
  WHERE ParentID is null

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    h.ID, 
    h.NAME,
    h.ParentID, 
    cte.Depth + 1,
    cte.ThePath + convert(varbinary(max), convert(varbinary(2), h.ID)) as ThePath
  FROM   hierarchy AS h 
  INNER JOIN CTE as cte
  ON h.ParentID = cte.ID
)
SELECT 
  ID, 
  NAME, 
  ParentID, 
  Depth, 
  ThePath
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY ThePath
```

This displays the results like this.

```
ID          NAME                           ParentID    Depth       ThePath
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ---------------
0           Happy Event                    NULL        0           0x0000
2           Very Happy Event               0           1           0x00000002
4           Happiest Event                 2           2           0x000000020004
1           Sad Event                      NULL        0           0x0001
3           Very Sad Event                 1           1           0x00010003
5           Unpleasant Event               1           1           0x00010005
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to convert to `int` first, and also that `varbinary(2)` will only allow ID values up to `65535`.

Comment: @ErickE thanks. You are right. I removed the convert to int. I realize varbinary(2) is limited, but I thought it would be work for this example. I originally had varbinary(3), but it seemed overkill.

Answer (score -2):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE hierarchy (ID INT, NAME NVARCHAR(30), ParentID INT)
INSERT INTO hierarchy VALUES 
(0,'Happy Event'     ,NULL),
(1,'Sad Event'       ,NULL),
(2,'Very Happy Event',0),
(3,'Very Sad Event'  ,1),
(4,'Happiest Event'  ,2),
(5,'Unpleasant Event',1)
```

**Query** (Sql Server 2005+)

```
;WITH ClassHierarchy_CTE (CID, ClassID_Join, Level)
AS
(
SELECT ID, ID AS Join_Class, 0
FROM   hierarchy AS c

UNION ALL
SELECT cte.CID, h.ParentID, Level + 1
FROM   hierarchy AS h INNER JOIN ClassHierarchy_CTE as cte
ON     h.ID = cte.ClassID_Join
)
SELECT    CTE.CID      AS ID
        , Hic.NAME     AS NAME
        , Hic.ParentID AS ParentEvent 
        , COUNT(*)-1   AS Depth    
FROM    ClassHierarchy_CTE CTE INNER JOIN hierarchy Hic
ON      CTE.CID = Hic.ID
WHERE   ClassID_Join IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CTE.CID, Hic.NAME, Hic.ParentID
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦══════════════════╦═════════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║       NAME       ║ ParentEvent ║ Depth ║
╠════╬══════════════════╬═════════════╬═══════╣
║  0 ║ Happy Event      ║ NULL        ║     0 ║
║  1 ║ Sad Event        ║ NULL        ║     0 ║
║  2 ║ Very Happy Event ║ 0           ║     1 ║
║  3 ║ Very Sad Event   ║ 1           ║     1 ║
║  4 ║ Happiest Event   ║ 2           ║     2 ║
║  5 ║ Unpleasant Event ║ 1           ║     1 ║
╚════╩══════════════════╩═════════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: How does this answer the requirement "Events with that have a non-null ParentEvent appear directly after the event with the ID matching the ParentEvent"? You have "Very Happy Event" with a ParentID of 0 *below* the parent event of 1.

Comment: @ErikE CID, NAME and ParentID are comming from the table itself, I have just changed the names of the columns. only the depth column is coming from cte and in cte I have just counted all the parents for all the above a child record - 1, This is how its shown in the required result set.

Comment: The required result set shows ID order 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5. Your query shows ID order 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. It's incorrect.

Comment: @ErikE Text from question: `As long as the results satisfy the previous two conditions, the order the results appear in does not matter`

Comment: I agree with you! May I kindly direct your attention to one of those conditions: "Events with that have a non-null ParentEvent appear **directly after** the event with the ID mathching the ParentEvent". The row in your Result Set `3, 'Very Sad Event', 1, 1` is NOT **directly after** its parent event 1! How is this satisfying the conditions?